# How can I justify that $a^{2}=e$ and $b^{3}=e$ for an Abelian group of order 6?

Tags: abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

I've been reading a proof that an Abelian group of order 6 is cyclic and I am not quite sure how we can justify that in the computations $a^{2}=e$ and $b^{3}=e$. What theorem or proposition is being used to justify that claim? I feel like this is fundamental about groups that I lost somewhere along the way.

Comment: Also, another tip specifically regarding groups of order $6$: there's only two groups, $S_3$ and $\Bbb Z / 6 \Bbb Z$. Only one of them is abelian.

Comment: An abelian group of order $6$ has two non-trivial subgroups. If a subgroup is of order $m$ , then it contains an element of order $m$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Cauchy's theorem, that if a prime $p$ divides the group order, so if $p\mid 6$, then the group has an element of order $p$. Apply this for $p=2$ and for $p=3$ and you will obtain the claim.